Cannot find 'PFInstallation' in scope when trying to configure push notifications iOS
I'm trying to configure push notifications with back4app backend in my iOS app using this guide: https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/push-notifications/ios-send-push-notification-from-server
import UIKit
import ParseSwift
import StoreKit
import UserNotifications
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let server: ServerFeaturesProtocols = ParseServerService()
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: "applicationID", clientKey: "clientKey", serverURL: URL(string: "https://serverURl")!)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound, .carPlay]) { granted, error in
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
        print("sessionToken \(PSUser.current?.sessionToken)")
    
        if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
           FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {
            if let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped) {
                let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            }
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SubscriptionManager.shared)
        SubscriptionManager.shared.fetchAvailableProducts()
        return true
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {}
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        createInstallationOnParse(deviceTokenData: deviceToken)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(SubscriptionManager.shared)
    }
    
    func createInstallationOnParse(deviceTokenData:Data){
        if let installation = PFInstallation.current {
            installation.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceTokenData)
            installation.saveInBackground {
                (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
                if (success) {
                    print("You have successfully saved your push installation to Back4App!")
                } else {
                    if let myError = error {
                        print("Error saving parse installation \(myError.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Uknown error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I receive an error: Cannot find 'PFInstallation' in scope although I have all imports
I tried replace PFInstallation with ParseInstallation but it didn't work

There's a template provided by back4app that can assist you with the push notifications for iOS using ParseSwift:
https://github.com/templates-back4app/PushNotificationSwiftUI
